# How to customize the volusion store and integrate a "get a quote" option

Tags: volusion

I want to customize the store and have an option for the users to get a quote for the products, once clicked on the option it will send mail to admin of store about the same along with the product ID

Let me know how can this be achieved ?

Comment: It can probably be done through programming. In its current form, this is too broad for Stack Overflow though.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar ... added a Make Offer button for any product over X amount of money.  Here's what my code in the template.html looks like...

```
 var price = $("span[itemprop='price']").html();
 if ( price != null && price != 'undefined' ) {
      price = price.replace("$", "");
      price = price.replace(",", "");
      var pname= $("span[itemprop='name']").html();
      pname= pname.replace(/\W+/g, "_")
      var pcode = $('.product_code').html();
      if ( price > 50 )
      {

     $('.vCSS_input_addtocart').after('<p><input type="button" style=" text-shadow:    -1px -1px 0 #006d72,    1px -1px 0 #006d72,    -1px 1px 0 #006d72,     1px 1px 0 #006d72;border-radius: 6px;  border: 1px solid #6E2B62; background-color:#009DA5; color:white" value="Make An Offer" onclick="window.open( \'/v/vspfiles/makeanoffer.asp?ProductCode='+pcode+'&price='+price+'&pname='+pname+' \',\'_blank\', \'width=300px, height=500px\' ) " />');
```

Then I have a custom ASP page that handles the email, which is another can of worms.  You could more easily use the built-in email form, which is explained here...
https://support.volusion.com/hc/en-us/articles/209448057-How-to-Create-a-Storefront-Email-Contact-Form

Good luck!